# Content-type Multiple Parameters

Tags: http, response-headers

As per the RFC link [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17)content-type is defined as

```
 Content-Type   = "Content-Type" ":" media-type
```

Media-type is defined as

```
media-type     = type "/" subtype *( ";" parameter )
type           = token
subtype        = token
```

So, as per this

```
ContentType: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
```

is a valid. Can a ContentType have multiple parameters? For example:

```
ContentType: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="urn:CreateCredential"
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current spec is RFC 7231, not RFC 2616.

But yes:

```
*( ";" parameter )
```

indicates that there can be multiple parameters.